# Curious hyperbolic metric interesting?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, hyperbolic-geometry

Knowing that distance in polar coordinates is minimized by metric $ ds^2 = (r^2 + r^{\prime 2})\,d\theta^2 $ as representing a straight line geodesic in the plane, I was curious to know about the metric:

$$ ds^2 = (r^2 - r^{\prime 2}) \, d\theta^2 \tag{0}$$

$$ s = \int \sqrt{ r^2 - r^{\prime 2}} d\theta  \tag{1}$$

(Primed with respect to $\theta$).

With Euler-Lagrange equation in Calculus of variations  we find solutions

$$ F = \sqrt{ r^2 - r^{\prime 2}} \tag{2}$$

$$ F - r^{\prime}\,\partial F/ \partial r^{\prime} = const \tag{3}$$

$$ \frac{r^2}{\sqrt{ r^2 - r^{\prime 2}}} = const. \tag{4} $$

$$ r^{\prime \prime }  = 2 r^{\prime 2}/r - r  \tag{5}$$

Please note that by a simple change of sign of above, the straight line  can be obtained by integration with constants $ (p,\alpha) $  in polar form as:

$$ r^{\prime \prime }  = 2 r^{\prime 2}/r + r, \quad p =  r \cos(\theta- \alpha)  \tag{6}$$

Now (5) integrates to :

$$ 1/r = e^\theta /2a + e^ {-\theta}/2b \tag{7}$$

$(a,b) $ are arbitrary constants. When $a=b,\, r = a\, sech \,\theta $

This is a spiral falling to the origin, the projection is *exactly the same* as the polar projection of the central (Beltrami) pseudosphere asymptotic line or geodesic.

So the metric is fundamentally and qualitatively a *hyperbolic metric*. It remains to be shown that the lines could be *hyperbolcally* geodesic *as well in* $\mathbb R^3 $ in this particular case.

An integrand of differential equation gives plot of the curve with B.C. $ r(0) =2, r^{\prime }(0) = 0 $ with plot:

[image: curious metric]

The condition $ a=b$ implies hyperbolic geodesics on Beltrami pseudosphere. When $ a\ne b$ typically meridian resembles a hypo pseudosphere containing the curious metric. $ \phi =\psi$ (slope and inclination to meridian) for the former and $ \phi +\psi = \pi/2  $ for meridian shown.

[image: Curious Merian a ne b]

I expected in a not too wild and off-tangent imagination to mirror a skewed Pythagorean relation ( hyperbolic?) $ c^2 = (a^2-b^2) $ of equation tagged (0) geometrical relation being valid and should show up somewhere, but I cannot recognize it anywhere.

Sorry for the subjective nature of query, I am posting it despite whatever vagueness that is going with it ... and I do appreciate not down-voting as stimulus to such research inquiries..

Comment: Your metric is reminiscent of the Minkowski metric in Relativity, although of course there the time coordinate is not a derivative with respect to an angle.  Maybe there is a connection there?

Comment: Yes and and in addition the hyperbolic metric nature is inherent in it, as you can see it. So I posted it with such a research motivation also.

Comment: I just love the title of this question

Comment: Nice that you love it. Am still trying to search for the hidden Pythagoras relation!